# Using WaitForMultipleObjects() with ACE_SOCK_Stream - get event only when there's data

Tags: ace, socketstream, waitformultipleobjects

Is it possible to use WaitForMultipleObjects() with ACE_SOCK_Stream, and make it return only when there's data to read from it?

I tried to following:

```
    // set some params
    DWORD handlesCount = 1;
    DWORD timeoutMs = 5 * 1000;
    HANDLE* handles = new HANDLE[handlesCount]; 
    handles[0] = sock_stream.get_handle();

    while (true) {
        int ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(handlesCount, handles, false, timeoutMs);
        std::cout << "Result: " << ret << std::endl;
```

But the WaitForMultipleObjects() returns immediately the socket stream index, indicating that its ready (it prints 0 in an endless loop).

The socket is accepted via a `ACE_SOCK_Acceptor` (ACE_SOCK_Acceptor->accept()).

How do I make WaitForMultipleObjects() wait until the socket has data to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket handle is not suitable for use in WFMO. You should use [WSAEventSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx) to associate the desired event(s) with an event handle that's registered with WFMO.

Since you are also familiar with ACE, you can check the source code for ace/WFMO_Reactor.cpp, register_handler() method to see a use-case and how it works with WFMO.

Comment: Hi just wondering since you seem to know a little about ACE - whats the main difference between WFMO_Reactor and a normal ACE_Reactor? Because I see both behave pretty much the same as long as you want the WFMO bWaitAll flag false (and I know there's also the lower-handle higher-priority thing in WFMO, but is that it?). Basically I'm trying to figure out if I have any actual reason to use WFMO reactor and not the basic one. Thanks!

Comment: There is a very nice discussion of this question in The ACE Programmer's Guide (which I co-authored), section 7.7, pg 181. http://www.riverace.com/acebooks/index.htm#apg. But if you use ACE_Reactor::instance() on Windows, you're getting ACE_WFMO_Reactor.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much and I'm sure the book is great, but maybe you could give a short answer for it here? Just the key point perhaps, a "spoiler" if you will (since I won't buy a whole book just for a single question). Thanks :)